# Aurelia with VS2015: Modifications to view not visible to the client

Tags: aurelia

I'm using Aurelia with Visual Studio 2015. I started with the project as an empty ASP.NET 4.6 project. But when I change my view, I don't the see the new html elements on the browser side.  It seems like the browser is caching it and not getting the new view from my server.

From the F12 tools window, I see no HTTP traffic going to the server except the fetch to get data from the Web Api service.

What server configuration is necessary to make my code updates visible on the browser?

Comment: Are you sure there is not any error on the web page?

Comment: There is no server error.  It is looking to be more about client side (browser) caching and not server configuration.

Comment: I'm talking about client-side. Did you see in the browser's console if is there any error?

Comment: I apologize, Fabio, for misreading your question.  The answer is:  I am not finding any error on the browser's console.  I still could not figure out how to refresh the pages on the client without the F12 tools for disabling the cache.  I was expecting CTR-R would refresh the pages.

Answer (score 3):

I disable caching ... In Chrome, F12 and then click the Network tab.  Check the "Disable cache" checkbox.  Ctrl-F5 to clear and refresh.  After that, the network tab shows request going out with HTTP Status 200 response and I see the changes.  [BUT WHAT IF:  I don't want to use the developer tools to control the caching.  I just want the module loader to always get the file from the server?]

Comment: I did not test this but maybe it will work: https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/94

Answer (score 1):

By default, IIS allows browsers to cache static content such as html, and image files. To avoid that, you need to disable static content cache in the web config file as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache"/>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

UPDATE:

You also need to clear the browser cache because the html files are already cached and therefore the browser will not request them to the server. Once the browser cache is cleared and the configuration in place, you will not experience the problem anymore.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your suggestion.  It did not work because it appears to be client caching.  I still had to use the F12 developer tools Disable caching option.

Comment: Clear browser cache and it will not occur again